# How do I find messages in Gmail that have attachments?

Tags: gmail, search, attachment

I know I can see which messages have attachments by the 'paper-clip' icon, but I need to find messages from a certain sender that have attachments.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- `has:attachment` — show mails which have an attachment
- `filename:xyz` — search for attachments based on type or name

Comment: Also, for reference: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=7190

Comment: Is there also a way to search for attachments of a certain size or name?

Comment: The filename: parameter will search for a filename, as far as I am aware there is no way of searching by size.

Comment: You can search for multiple filenames all at once too. For example, I have a "Video Attachments" quick link that searches for "filename:{asf asx avi divx flv m4v mkv mov mp4 mpeg mpg ogm wmv}".

Answer (score 3):

If you click on the "Show Search Options" link to the right of the search input fields you are able to specify additional parameters for your search, which include "has attachment" and "from" a specific sender.

If you prefer manually typing your queries, `from:(x@y.com) has:attachment` will produce the same results.

Answer (score 2):

Type "has:attachment" in the search field. If you need to find attachments often, you can click the "Add a Quick Link" button in the "Quick Link" section of the side bar when you are viewing the search results.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Pimp My Gmail](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/75047) – it’s an amazing Greasemonkey script that is compatible with Google Chrome, Firefox and Opera. It helps you to quickly see the icon representing the attached file extension in front of the Email subject and hovering the icon will let you know the full name of the attached file.

Comment: Is that script downloadable at your website or one of your products, or is that a signature-spam line?

Answer (score -1):

Download MetisMe for Gmail today-  www.metisme.com for easier Gmail attachment management.

You don’t find something in your e-mail (especially files), you get stressed and you wish for a quick solution. We are the solution here.

What we do at [MetisMe](http://www.metisme.com/download/)-

MetisMe stacks all your attachments in G-mail under a single tab (the way you view all files in your local drive) . It allows you to easily search and share with your team or your friends. You could integrate your favorite cloud drive with Gmail, sync the attachments that you would like to and share it.  It is a very simple & useful tool to not only increase productivity but also helps you save a lot of time and reduce stress. In fact you now have a complete e-archiving solution with you for zero cost!

It is best explained when tried for real. Do try it for FREE here – www.metisme.com and drop in an e-mail to me if you find it interesting. Please do write back if you have any queries at shalintj@metisme.com.  I will be happy to answer them.

Comment: Are you affiliated to MetisMe?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra It sure looks like it from the email address in the answer.

Comment: @Alex tldr. Thanks for clearing though.